# Is there a Stata package for stacked marginsplots or coefficients from multiple equations?

Tags: plot, average, stata, survey, coefficients

Is there a package in Stata that can generate a stacked coefficient plot like this one shown below? My dataset is from a survey that asks people to rate on a scale of 0-100 about 35 different groups (e.g. evangelical, immigrant, police, etc). I want to compare the average rating different groups of people like Democrat/Republican, Men/Women gave of the 35 different groups. I've run a simple OLS regression [GROUP FEELING THERMOMETER] ON PARTYID[DEMOCRAT=1, REPUBLICAN=0] followed by marginsplot, but it's just one chart.

```
*Marginplot
foreach var in Women_2019x1 {
regress `var' demgop [aweight=weight2_2019]
margins, over(demgop)
marginsplot, horizontal recast(scatter) title(`: variable label `var'') xline(0) xscale(range(0100))
```

}

I've tried Combomarginsplot but it creates separate graphs, not a stacked one.

```
        foreach var in Women_2019x1 {
    regress `var' demgop [aweight=weight2_2019]
    margins, over(demgop) saving(file1, replace)
        * margins, dydx(*) post
    marginsplot, horizontal recast(scatter) title(`: variable label `var'') xline(0) xscale(range(0100))
   }
        combomarginsplot file1 file2, labels ("Women" "Men") by(demgop)
```

I've tried coefplot, but it holds the results in the constant (linear prediction) without labels identifying which group is rating which of the 35 survey items.

```
        foreach var in  Women_2019x1 bw_2019x1 ft_black_2017x1 Democrats_2019x1 ft_jew_2017x1 ft_asian_2017x1 ft_gays_2016x1 hw_2019x1 ft_hisp_2017x1 ft_immig_2016x1 ww_2019x1 rbw_2019x1 pbw_2019x1 cities_2019x1 bm_2019x1 hm_2019x1 Men_2019x1 bc_2019x1 ft_muslim_2017x1 ft_christ_2017x1 towns_2019x1 pww_2019x1 wr_2019x1 pbm_2019x1 rbm_2019x1 hc_2019x1 wm_2019x1 pwm_2019x1 rww_2019x1 wc_2019x1 ft_evang_2017x1 rwm_2019x1  wec_2019x1  Republicans_2019x1  {
    regress `var' if demgop==1 [aweight=weight2_2019]
    est store `var'1
    regress `var' if demgop==0 [aweight=weight2_2019]
    est store `var'2
    }
    coefplot Women_2019x11 Women_2019x12 bw_2019x11 bw_2019x12 ft_black_2017x11 ft_black_2017x12 Democrats_2019x11 Democrats_2019x12 ft_jew_2017x11 ft_jew_2017x12 ft_asian_2017x11 ft_asian_2017x12 ft_gays_2016x11 ft_gays_2016x12 hw_2019x11 hw_2019x12 ft_hisp_2017x11 ft_hisp_2017x12 ft_immig_2016x11 ft_immig_2016x12 ww_2019x11 ww_2019x12 rbw_2019x11 rbw_2019x12 pbw_2019x11 pbw_2019x12 cities_2019x11 cities_2019x12 bm_2019x11 bm_2019x12 hm_2019x11 hm_2019x12 Men_2019x11 Men_2019x12 bc_2019x11 bc_2019x12 ft_muslim_2017x11 ft_muslim_2017x12 ft_christ_2017x11 ft_christ_2017x12 towns_2019x11 towns_2019x12 pww_2019x11 pww_2019x12 wr_2019x11 wr_2019x12 pbm_2019x11 pbm_2019x12 rbm_2019x11 rbm_2019x12 hc_2019x11 hc_2019x12 wm_2019x11 wm_2019x12 pwm_2019x11 pwm_2019x12 rww_2019x11 rww_2019x12 wc_2019x11 wc_2019x12 ft_evang_2017x11 ft_evang_2017x12 rwm_2019x11 rwm_2019x12 wec_2019x11 wec_2019x12 Republicans_2019x11    Republicans_2019x12 ///
    ,legend(off)
```

Is there another package in Stata that could produce this stacked coefficient plot of means by group?   Thanks very much in advance for your help.

[image: Python Stacked Coefficient Plot, Shows average ratings among age groups of the 35 groups]

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called multicoefplot which permits to plot multiple models within the same window. Try `ssc install multicoefplot`